# generate new Certificate Signing Request after upgrading to Snow Leopard?

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, provisioning

i recently updated my mac to Snow Leopard. But due to it all my provisioning profiles have been deleted. I didnt keep the backup for my keychain so i downloaded my **Certificate Signing Request** again from apple developer program and installed it in my mac.So to upload one of my old application i created a new App Id with a new Provisioning profile..I did not have **MobileDevice folder** in my Library so i created it manually and copied the profile to that folder..Now in my xcode when i try to select my provisioning profile it does not show any.I selected the **Iphone Distribution** profile(Xcode3.2 might automatcally detect it) but it doesnt work.I manually entered the name of my profile via other but still it gives me error.

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Do i have to create a new Certificate Signing Request for Os 10.6??
Or creating MobileDevice folder manually wont work??
What should i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to generate a new certificate. Unless you exported your previous certificates with your private key.